# How to display map with previously dragged or moved position on map

Tags: swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I want to position a map to previously scrolled/dragged position not to user's location using GMSMapView

Example - User's current location is xyz and then user moves/scrolls/drags map to abc location and navigate to some other screen, and when user comes back to map screen again then map should be centre to abc not to user's current location xyz.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

when you move/scrolls/drags store current camera position by `mMap.getCameraPosition().target`in sharedPreference or app Constant, do not store in current activity it will destroy after change activity, so when you again call this(MAP) activity set again camera position to you map and pass stored value (LatLong) like this `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(passStoredLatLongHere, 14));`